# Meaning of штатный and внештатный?

Tags: значения

Штатный appears in contexts referencing "staff" and "standard" (dissimilar words in English).

What is the best way to grasp the meaning of word штатный?  Is it only used in specific technical set phrases?

The other half of the question is внештатный. Внештатный can be (easily) translated in all observed contexts as "freelance".  Why does штатный appear to be so much more complex in usage?

Can штатный be used as the opposite of внештатный?

Штатный Examples:

1. Установка багажника на штатные места в крыше.
2. Штатное расписание имеет большое значение для эффективного использования работников.
3. Сейчас штатная численность армии РФ будет составлять 1 миллион 885 тыс. человек.
4. Широкий выбор штатных головных устройств в Екатеринбурге по низким ценам! (This, from a web site selling car audio display boards.)

Внештатный Examples:

1. По словам главного внештатного специалиста по акушерству и гинекологии, к концу 2013 количество родов в регионе по итогам года достигнет 50 тыс.
2. Может ли внештатный сотрудник полиции применять свои полномочия при прикреплённым за ним полицейским?
3. В общем чем хорошо быть внештатным журналистом и чем плохо?
4. Внештатные переводчики работают на дому, получая заказы лично в нашем офисе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examples 1 and 4 from штатный are technically correct, but it's not a common use of the word.
In general the opposite of штатный is внештатный OR нештатный. More about this [here](http://ask.fm/russian/answers/27048848956).

Be aware of another use of opposite for штатный:

- Нештатная ситуация (чрезвычайная ситуация, не предусмотренная регламентом) instead of внештатная ситуация that is not correct.
- The same is for режим: штатный/нештатный режим, not внештатный режим.

Comment: And what is "a common use of the word"?

Comment: @bipll, Examples 2 and 3 are. Don't get me wrong, 1 and 4 are in use, but I believe mostly "стандартный" is used in these cases.

Answer (score 3):

We can observe two main meanings of the adjective *штатный*--*on the staff* (штатный сотрудник) and *regular, standard* (штатные места,штатная ситуация).

The antonyms are respectively  внештатный (сотрудник) and нештатный (нештатная ситуация).

Answer (score 3):

Russian language is very complex in terms of how similar types of words are consructed. "Внештатный" is only opposite of "штатный" in the meaning of "internal staff", derived from "вне штата" (outside of the staff); for the meaning of "standard" the opposite is "нештатный", because it is not related to being in or out of something.

Answer (score 2):

Штатный (сотрудник) means a full-time employee working constantly for the enterprise, внештатный is the opposite. "Штатное расписание" is a formal document at an enterprise establishing the number of employees in each position for a department. By extension, штатный  (even less formal "родной" can be heard instead) can be applied sometimes to things specially intended for usage as a part of a particular product. The word "внештатный" is not used for things or events, *нештатный* is used instead: "нештатная ситуация" means an unwanted/unexpected situation or emergency.

Comment: it does not mean a "full-time" employee. It only means that a person is present in the list of employees. You can still work half-time or whatever. I think it is like an employee vs a contractor in English